PHP DateTime class returns wrong previous or next month on 31.05.2024
I am developing a WordPress plugin called WP Date and Time Shortcode which counts to the PHP DateTime and DateTimeZone classes to display previous, current or next date and time based on some attributes and a number of functionalities.
I received a bug report which seems to be true but surprising because I am using the DateTime and the DateTimeZone in the plugin correctly.
The plugin has been working for more than 4 years and never had this issue before.
So I created some test code (separately from the plugin) to test. And the result is wrong indeed.
I created a DateTime object with a DateTimeZone object (UTC) and I wanted to modify one month forward (next month) or backward (previous month) from May 31, 2024. Unfortunately the result is not correct. If the date is May 31, 2024 the next month must be June and the previous April.
$tz1 = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$dt1 = new DateTime('today', $tz1); // use '31.05.2024' instead of 'now' to test if other date
$dt1->modify("next month"); // or "+1 month", must return June
echo $dt1->format("F"); // shows July

$tz2 = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
$dt2 = new DateTime('today', $tz2); // use '31.05.2024' instead of 'now' to test if other date
$dt2->modify("previous month"); // or "-1 month", must return April
echo $dt2->format("F"); // shows May

Can you please confirm if you have the same issue with any version of PHP or let me know where do you think is the problem? It seems like a PHP problem for me.

I think it rolls over because next month is only 30 days so does not have a 31st of June . If you use modify('first day of next month') (or last month) it seems to work. It might be a bug but I don't know what the correct date would be since going to the 30th would mean you've added less than a full month

PHP documentation for DateTime::modify warns "Beware when adding or subtracting months", but does not explain why. See example #2 on the linked page.

If you want to fix it for sure, you have to get the months and use the month number to get the previous and next months .
